# EF: copy an entity with nested data but not with subnested data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose this is my Entity architecture

```
class A 
{
    public int AID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

class B 
{
    public int BID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

class C 
{
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I.e. every `A` has a list of `B`'s and every `B` has a list of `C`'s.

I now want to make a copy of `A` with the following requirements

- The copy of `A` must also copy all of its `B`'s.
- Every new B must **NOT** copy its' `C`'s

I try to achieve this the following way

```
// Retrieve the original one.
var a = await _dbContext.As
    .Include(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.Cs))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.AID == 1);

a.Name = "copy";
_dbContext.Add(a);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But I have tried various techniques and none of them work.

- Manually looping over all C's and attach them to the context.
- Looping over all `Cs` and setting their status to `unchanged`.
- Looping over all `Bs` and assign a tracked instance of their `Cs` (`b.Cs = _dbContext.Cs.where(...).ToList()`)
- Looping over all `Bs` and assigning a `new C { CID = Eixsting_ID }`

EF still tries to create new `C` entities (which fail because of constraints in the DB).

We are using the old Entity Framework (not EF Core) in .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: So by Bs not copying Cs do you mean that the new Bs get the exact same Cs or no Cs at all?

Comment: Keeping the exact same C's is not possible, since the C's can have only one parent. I.e., the B copies will get a new PK but the C's foreign key column can either reference the old B **or** the new B, but not both.

Comment: Which means that B-C should be a many to many relationship. Is that what you actually want?